# Current directory in java properties file

Tags: java, properties, path

Is there any way of specifying the current directory in a java properties file?

i.e. something like:

```
fileLocation={currentDir}/fileName.txt
```

Comment: What about "fileLocation=./fileName.txt", or just "fileLocation=fileName.txt"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Properties files do not have any builtin macro facilities. You can programmatically get the currect directory of the user running the Java app through the [user.dir system property](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you set the systems property in this way? For example, if I want to temporarily set the user.dir to some specific directory? I tried changing it before running a unit test, but it still wasn't able to load the file, even though the path returned from getProperty("user.dir") was correct....

Comment: No, the system property is set when the JVM is started, but later changes to it have no effect. I don't think it's possible to change the working directory of a running JVM.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure it just defaults to the current directory, if not you can do

```
fileLocation="./fileName.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any direct solution for this problem.
You can load the URL to the properties file and then load the filename from that file:

```
ClassLoader loader = YourClass.class.getClassLoader(); 
URL resourceURL =loader.getResource("check.properties");
String fileToLoad = resourceURL.getPath() + <fileNameFromPropertyFile>;
```